# How to mocking created time in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, sqlalchemy, mocking

I use SQLAlchemy in my Flask application. In my tests I try mocking auto time create and update for my entries. But I don't understand how it work for SQLAlchemy. For example I try mocking datetime creating with [freezgun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun), but is failure. For example:

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now())
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

class ViewTestCase(AppliactionTestCase):
    def test(self):
        with freeze_time("2014-06-01 16:00:00"):
            db.session.add(Entry())
            db.session.commit()
        entry = db.session.query(Entry).first()
        self.assertEqual(entry.created, datetime(2014, 6, 1, 16, 0, 0))
```

And one more question. How forced save entry without changes, if I need refresh `updated` for entry?

Answer (score 5):

sqlalchemy provide the hook  `sqlalchemy.event` api to patch a query session.

**prerequisite**: flask-sqlalchemy, pytest, freezengun, contextlib

with the example with flask-sqlalchemy which @prokoptesev used:

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now())
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
```

Just write a pytest fixtures to patch the row create time:

```
import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import event
from contextlib import contextmanager
from freezegun import freeze_time

import Entry
# if you want the code be commonly used, change Entry to db.Model instead


@contextmanager
def patch_time(time_to_freeze, tick=True):
    with freeze_time(time_to_freeze, tick=tick) as frozen_time:
        def set_timestamp(mapper, connection, target):
           now = datetime.datetime.now()
           if hasattr(target, 'created'):
               target.created = now
           if hasattr(target, 'updated'):
               target.updated = now
        event.listen(Entry, 'before_insert', set_timestamp,
                     propagate=True)
        yield frozen_time
        event.remove(Entry, 'before_insert', set_timestamp)


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def patch_current_time():
    return patch_time
```

Then write a pytest type test case:

```
def test_patch_insert_time(patch_current_time, assertions):
    with patch_current_time("2014-06-01 16:00:00", tick=False):
        db.session.add(Entry())
        db.session.commit()
    entry = db.session.query(Entry).first()
    assert entry.created == datetime(2014, 6, 1, 16, 0, 0)
```

If somebody use `unittools` or other test package, you can also use the patch_time function directly:

```
class ViewTestCase(AppliactionTestCase):
    def test(self):
        with patch_time("2014-06-01 16:00:00", tick=False):
            db.session.add(Entry())
            db.session.commit()
        entry = db.session.query(Entry).first()
        self.assertEqual(entry.created, datetime(2014, 6, 1, 16, 0, 0))
```

happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Freezegun only patches `datetime.datetime.now`. You can solve it in one of two ways:

1. Use `mock.patch` to patch `db.func.now()`, or (simpler, in my opinion),
2. Use `default=datetime.datetime.now`, so freezegun will patch it correctly.

Comment: It's not work for me. I don't know how it work under hood, but if I use `default=datetime.datetime.now` in model, datetime patched, but in saved model `created` return current time.

Comment: How I can patch `db.func.now`?
Correct me if I'm wrong. `db.func.now` is database function when saved model. May be patching it's not correct?

Comment: Where is the `Entry` class relative to your test?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.