# Why doesn't FreezeGun work with SQLAlchemy default values?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, freezegun

I created a SQLAlchemy app with the following model:

```
class MyObject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_object'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    some_string = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I created this migration file to go along with it:

```
"""
Junk

Revision ID: 4b6fffffffff_
Revises: 4b6e7775856f
Create Date: 2019-11-08 00:31:13.297355

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '4b6fffffffff_'
down_revision = '4b6e7775856f'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy_utils
from sqlalchemy import false


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'my_object',
        sa.Column('created', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('updated', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('some_string', sa.String(length=20), nullable=False),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
```

Now I have this unit-test case which uses [Freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/0.1.11/):

```
def test_freeze_gun_on_sql_alchemy(self):
    now_time = datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=4, day=1, hour=5, minute=12, second=32, microsecond=543)
    freezer = freeze_time(now_time)
    freezer.start()
    print 'datetime.datetime.now() = {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
    m = MyObject(some_string="Hello World")
    db.session.add(m)
    db.session.commit()
    freezer.stop()
    print 'm.created = {}'.format(m.created)
```

This test case produces this output:

```
datetime.datetime.now() = 2012-04-01 05:12:32.000543
m.created = 2019-11-09 04:04:55
```

Why is `m.created` the current wall-clock time instead of the FreezeGun time?? The two should be the same.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116925/1742777), Freezegun patches `datetime.datetime.now()`. My test case confirms that. So then why/how is a different value being stored in the Database??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `MyObject` lives in the module namespace, it, and its class level attributes are evaluated at compile time. This happens before Freezegun has patched `datetime.datetime.now`, so the column default functions still point to the stdlib implementation.

Here's a simpler example:

```py
import datetime
from freezegun import freeze_time


class MyObject:
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now


now_time = datetime.datetime(
    year=2012, month=4, day=1, hour=5, minute=12, second=32, microsecond=543
)
freezer = freeze_time(now_time)
freezer.start()
print(datetime.datetime.now())  # 2012-04-01 05:12:32.000543
print(MyObject().dt_now())  # 2019-11-09 15:44:29.437382
freezer.stop()
```

Now instantiate Freezegun before setting the class attribute:

```py
now_time = datetime.datetime(
    year=2012, month=4, day=1, hour=5, minute=12, second=32, microsecond=543
)
freezer = freeze_time(now_time)
freezer.start()


class MyObject:
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now


print(datetime.datetime.now())  # 2012-04-01 05:12:32.000543
print(MyObject().dt_now())  # 2012-04-01 05:12:32.000543
freezer.stop()
```

Referencing [this issue](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/306), wrapping your defaults in a lambda works:

```py
created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now())
```

...as that prevents the stdlib function from being bound to the Column default. Or, ensure that the module where `MyObject` lives is imported after Freezegun is set.